# Yahoo YQL - list all tracks of a Release

Tags: yql, yahoo-pipes

In my current free-time project I am trying to fetch all songs from a given album.

Anyone, in Yahoo YQL, how is it possible to list all tracks of a given Release id?

Comment: what's the URL you're processing?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand ur question, I am looking for something like this:http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20music.video.popular&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20music.track.id%20where%20ids%3D%22745816%22 where the listing would be all tracks for a album id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can influence what is returned as part of the results of queries to the `music.release.id` table by specifying a `response` value.  In this case, you want track information for a release, so ask for `tracks`.

```
select * from music.release.id where ids="148083" and response="tracks"
```

Also see the [Release Service](http://developer.yahoo.com/music/api_guide/ReleaseService.html#AlbumReleasesByID) and 
[Release List responses](http://developer.yahoo.com/music/api_guide/ReleaseResponses.html#ReleaseListResponse) documentations.